# Is there OnSlideShowPageChange like API in PowerPoint JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, powerpoint, office-js

I am developing PowerPoint add-in using JavaScript API. This add-in needs to execute some action on change slides. But It seems that no API or methods get to achieve it.

I am looking for OnSlideShowPageChange(on VBA) like API.
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That API is not supported in the Office JavaScript APIs, but it is a great idea. Please suggest it at [Office Developer Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll suggest it at Office Developer Voice.